# MySQL insert if not exists/ignore

Tags: c#, mysql, insert, exists

So basically here's my table layout:

```
Type_Of     Agreement
iPad        Heyo! I'm an agreement!
iPod Touch  I'm another agreement!
```

Basically, I'm building an admin interface where an administrator can add new types. I'd like it to make it so he/she can't enter a new type that already exists. Basically, in the above example, if they were to enter 'iPad' in the new type box and press submit, it will simply be ignored or an error will be thrown or something.

Here's my existing MySQL statement:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO agreements (Type_Of, Agreement) VALUES (?, ?)
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("", Request.Form["pies"]);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("", "Wahey! A sample license!");
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?  If `INSERT IGNORE` isn't doing what you expected, do you have a `UNIQUE` key defined on `Type_Of`?

Comment: Derp. No I didn't. I forgot that part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

You need to define a `UNIQUE` index on `Type_Of`.  As explained in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-index.html):

> A `UNIQUE` index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a `UNIQUE` index permits multiple `NULL` values for columns that can contain `NULL`. If you specify a prefix value for a column in a `UNIQUE` index, the column values must be unique within the prefix.

Therefore:

```sql
ALTER TABLE agreements ADD UNIQUE INDEX (Type_Of);
```